# SQL server, como puedo convertir GETDATE () en un Int como YYYYMMDD

Tags: sql

Tengo este Stored Procedure que solo lee la fecha como Int Ejem. 20200311 y quiero correr el SP todos los dias con la informacion cargada de Hoy, pero no se como convertir el GETDATE () a esta forma

```
DECLARE @Date
DECLARE @date_start    INT
DECLARE @date_end      INT
DECLARE @id INT
DECLARE @SQL           NVARCHAR(MAX)
       SET @date_start = 20200201 --manage start date
       SET @date_end   = 20200229 () --manage end date
       SET @id = 184477 --change ident on demand
EXEC [dbo].[TempotalTable1] @date_start, @date_end, @id
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: Estás en SO en Español, traduce tu pregunta o terminará cerrada.

Comment: Listo, me equivoque de region, igual ya especifique lo que necesito

Comment: Deberías agregar el código

Comment: Me parece que estás pensando las cosas al revés. Las fechas siempre deben de estar en un tipo de dato de fecha, no enteros y no cadenas.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primer es convertir el `datetime` a una cadena que solo sea la fecha en formato `yyyymmdd` mediante el parámetro de estilo `112` y entonces una segunda conversión a un entero:

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112))
```

[Más info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

El formato ISO "`yyyyMMdd`" es un formato del tipo `varchar` y lo puedes conseguir con un simple `Convert`.

```
Declare @param varchar(8) = (select convert(varchar, getdate(), 112))
```

Si lo quieres forzar a `int` realizas un `Cast` del resultado

```
Declare @param int = (select CAST(convert(varchar, getdate(), 112) as int))
```